# How to map an array of integers as keys to dictionary values

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

If I have the following array and I want to create a string array containing the door prizes by mapping the mysteryDoors array as keys for the dictionary, and get the corresponding values into a new array.

Thus I would get a string array of ["Gift Card", "Car", "Vacation"] how can I do that?

```
let mysteryDoors = [3,1,2]

let doorPrizes = [
    1:"Car", 2: "Vacation", 3: "Gift card"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map()` each array element to the corresponding value in 
the dictionary. If it is *guaranteed* that all array elements are 
present as keys in the dictionary then you can do:

```
let mysteryDoors = [3, 1, 2]
let doorPrizes = [ 1:"Car", 2: "Vacation", 3: "Gift card"]

let prizes = mysteryDoors.map { doorPrizes[$0]! }
print(prizes) // ["Gift card", "Car", "Vacation"]
```

To avoid a runtime crash if a key is not present, use

```
let prizes = mysteryDoors.flatMap { doorPrizes[$0] }
```

to ignore unknown keys, or

```
let prizes = mysteryDoors.map { doorPrizes[$0] ?? "" }
```

to map unknown keys to a default string.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use `map`, then it would look something like the following:

```
let array = mysteryDoors.map { doorPrizes[$0] }
```

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the Apple Doc example code and changing it to what I need.  I believe this is it (Almost). Unfortunately it is now in string format with new lines...

```
let myPrizes = doorPrizes.map { (number) -> String in
    var output = ""
    output = mysteryDoors[number]!
    return output;
}
```

Comment: yes. and you can reduce it with `map{ mysteryDoors[$0]! }` as many others have answered.